# How to stop BeautifulSoup escaping inline javascript

Tags: python, escaping, beautifulsoup

I have discovered that BeautifulSoup 4 appears to escape some characters in inline javascript:

```
>>> print s
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Test page</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<!--
if (4 > 3 && 3 < 4) {
        console.log("js working");
}
//-->
</script>
</body>
</html>
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(s, 'html5lib')
>>> print soup
<html><head></head><body><doctype html="">


<h1>Test page</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
//&lt;!--
if (4 &gt; 3 &amp;&amp; 3 &lt; 4) {
        console.log("js working");
}
//--&gt;
</script>

</doctype></body></html>
>>> print soup.prettify()
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <doctype html="">
   <h1>
    Test page
   </h1>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    //&lt;!--
if (4 &gt; 3 &amp;&amp; 3 &lt; 4) {
        console.log("js working");
}
//--&gt;
   </script>
  </doctype>
 </body>
</html>
```

In case it's lost in the above, the key problem is that:

```
if (4 > 3 && 3 < 4)
```

gets converted into:

```
if (4 &gt; 3 &amp;&amp; 3 &lt; 4)
```

which doesn't work particularly well ...

I have tried the included formatters in the `prettify()` method, with no success.

So any idea how to stop the javascript being escaped?  Or how to unescape it before outputting it?

Comment: Note that it should be `<!-- //`, not `// <!--`. Makes no difference to the output though.

Comment: The `<!-- -->` comments are actually useless in Javascript because Javascript can make use of `<`, `&` and `>` characters just fine. You should really use `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` instead to 'escape' the content of a `<script>` tag properly.

Comment: This is a problem with the parser; it doesn't see the content as a comment, so the `<!--` and `-->` prefix and suffix are escaped.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - whichever version of the comment I use, or if I don't use the comment, the key problem is the `if` statement contents being escaped.  I'll update the question to make that clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** This bug was fixed in 4.2.0, released on 30-May-2013.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> bs4.__version__
'4.2.0'
>> s = """<DOCTYPE html>
... <html>
... <body>
... <h1>Test page</h1>
... <script type="text/javascript">
... //<!--
... if (4 > 3 && 3 < 4) {
...     console.log("js working");
... }
... //-->
... </script>
... </body>
... </html>
... """
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> print soup
<html><body><doctype html="">
<h1>Test page</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<!--
if (4 > 3 && 3 < 4) {
    console.log("js working");
}
//-->
</script>
</doctype></body></html>
```

If you are stuck using < 4.2 for some reason, I found this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3225671/58371). It seems to me you can do something similar: Walk the tree, using `prettyify()` on all tags except for the `script` tag that you somehow emit without escaping.